# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with template specialization for auto argument

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, template-specialization, auto

Playing with C++17 `auto` template arguments I've encountered another g++/clang++ disagreement.

Given the following simple code

```
template <auto>
struct foo;

template <int I>
struct foo<I>
 { };

int main ()
 {
   foo<42l> f42; // <--- long constant, not int constant

   (void)f42; // avoid the "unused variable" warning
 }
```

I see that clang++ (8.0.0, by example) compile the code where g++ (9.2.0, by example) gives the following error

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:12:13: error: aggregate 'foo<42> f42' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
   12 |    foo<42l> f42;
      |             ^~~
```

Both compilers compile if we use a `int` constant instead of a `long` constant

```
  foo<42>  f42;  // compile with both clang++ and g++
```

So I have two questions for C++ language layers

(1) it's legal, in C++17, specialize a template, declared receiving an `auto` template parameter, for a value of a specific type (as the `foo` specialization in my code)?

(2) if the answer to the preceding question is "yes", a template specialization can intercept a value of a different (but convertible) type?

Question (2) is almost: is right clang++ or g++?

Comment: what if you add `{}` - ie. `template <auto> struct foo {};` ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker - Compile also g++. But this seems to me almost obvious (is the answer to the first question is "yes", obviously): the `42l` case is intercepted by the generic `foo<auto>` version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a slightly different repro that doesn't rely on incomplete types:

```
template <auto> struct foo { static constexpr int value = 0; };
template <int I> struct foo<I> { static constexpr int value = 1; };

// ok on gcc, fires on clang which thinks foo<42L>::value is 1
static_assert(foo<42L>::value == 0);
```

This is a clang bug. `42L` clearly matches `auto`, no question there. But does it match `int I`? No, from [[temp.deduct.type]/19](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#19):

> If `P` has a form that contains `<i>`, and if the type of `i` differs from the type of the corresponding template parameter of the template named by the enclosing *simple-template-id*, deduction fails. If `P` has a form that contains `[i]`, and if the type of `i` is not an integral type, deduction fails. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<int i> class A { /* ... */ };
> template<short s> void f(A<s>);
> void k1() {
>   A<1> a;
>   f(a);             // error: deduction fails for conversion from int to short
>   f<1>(a);          // OK
> }
>
>
> template<const short cs> class B { };
> template<short s> void g(B<s>);
> void k2() {
>   B<1> b;
>   g(b);             // OK: cv-qualifiers are ignored on template parameter types
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

In order to see if `42L` matches the specialization, we need to *deduce* `int I` from `42L` and that fails. Hence, we stick with the primary specialization. clang does not do this. Filed [43076](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43076).